# How do I go around deploying my .env file to CodeBuild?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions, microservices, aws-codebuild

So, I'm setting up a CICD pipeline. I've created the CodeBuild project, which I'm testing out and running into this issue. The trigger for the build process is a push to my GitHub repo, and obviously, that push does not include my .env files as its added to .gitignore. But my Dockerfile (which of course is pushed) copies that .env file as shown below, and I'm getting an error because the .env file does not exist because of the reasons above. I know there is definitely a way of going around this but I've been searching and somehow can't seem to find an answer. I'm new to CI/CD and AWS so I guess that's a huge factor. But I'm building a docker image to the ECR registry, which my ECS task definitions and hence containers will pick up. I'm using AWS Fargate.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
# Builder container to compile typescript
FROM node:18-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
COPY .env .
RUN npm ci
COPY . . 
RUN npm run build

FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
COPY /.env .

RUN npm ci --omit=dev

COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist /app

EXPOSE 4001
CMD [ "node", "src/index.js"]
```

My buildspec.yml:

```
version: 0.2
env:
  variables:
    AWS_ACCOUNT_ID: "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-east-2"
    USERS_IMAGE_REPO: "xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-repo"
    U_IMAGE_TAG: "users"
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - echo $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID
      - aws --version
      - docker --version
      - DOCKER_LOGIN=$(aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION)
      - echo $DOCKER_LOGIN | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image..
      - cd users
      - docker build -t $USERS_IMAGE_REPO:uid .
      - docker tag $USERS_IMAGE_REPO:$U_IMAGE_TAG $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$USERS_IMAGE_REPO:$U_IMAGE_TAG
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker push $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION. amazonaws.com/$USERS_IMAGE_REPO:$U_IMAGE_TAG
      - printf '[{"name":"logistics-users","imageUri":"%s"}]' $USERS_IMAGE_REPO:$U_IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json
      - cat imagedefinitions.json
artifacts:
  files: imagedefinitions.json
```

Error from CodeBuild:
[image]

If you notice in my buildspec I use `cd users` because the project uses a microservice architecture and I want to enter the docker build context of the users microservice. My folder structure is like this:

```
root-project-folder
  - users
    - .env
    - Dockerfile
    - buildspec.yml
    - package*.json
    - .dockerignore
    ...
  - deliveries
  - payments
  - notifications
  - .gitignore
```

This build is only for the users service, I'd setup another builds for each of the other services as well. The other services have the same setup as the users service shown above too. If this is a wrong approach please let me know as well. I'm not too experienced with microservices yet too.

I've considered using environment variables on CodeBuild, but I'm thinking that's for variables needed for the build process and not for the actual source code/application to run, which is what I want. Because the .env contains db connection credentials, AWS credentials etc. stuff that I need for the application and not the image build process.

And not, its not .dockerignore. The dockerignore file is empty, so its not the culprit here.

Comment: I think you don't really need to copy the `.env` file into the image. Because when the `.env` is not there, then environment variables are typically loaded from the system environment variables of the operating system when it runs the container. So you can define the  variables in the codebuild which will use when it runs the container.

Comment: @PRATHEESHPC do I need to set the system environment variables first? Sorry, how do I do that? I'm all new to this.

Comment: `Because the .env contains db connection credentials`; you dont really need to setup the env variables for building the image, but it only required to configure before you run the container with this image.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I understand @PRATHEESHPC, so how do I configure it? Is it in the task definition or where?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I really didn't need to, as it's not even needed for the build. There are other options available for using .env including utilizing AWS Secrets Manager, uploading the .env file(s) to an s3 bucket, and using the ARN in the environment variable of the task definition, etc.

So what I did is that I removed the `COPY .env .` command from my Dockerfile, and deployed to Github, ran triggered the build, but then I added the environment variables to my task definition as follows:

```
...
"environment": [
      {
        "name": "KEY1",
        "value": "VALUE1"
      }
    ],
...
```

Then I referenced the variables via the usual process.env

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).